# Is it possible to send an extended version of a low-tier conference paper to a high quality journal?

Tags: journals, conference, computer-science

In Computer Science, it is common for extended version of conference papers to be submitted to journals. In this case, is it relevant which conference the paper was published in, for acceptance to a high quality journal? For example, is it possible for the extended version of a good paper from a low-quality conference to be accepted by a high-quality journal?

Comment: Is the extended paper that good? Because if the original paper was mediocre (and this is why it was send to a lower-tier conference) extending it might be not enough to salvage it.

Comment: @Alexandros Yes, the original paper was good too -- but had to be sent quickly because of time constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: yes.

The journal review process is generally completely independent of the conference review process.  You will likely face additional skepticism from the reviewers, who may well be rightly prejudiced against the original publication venue.  If your paper really *is* solidly good enough for the journal you send it to, however, it's likely to do just fine in review there.